# Widget not showing up in Unreal Engine 4, how can i fix this?

Tags: widget, unreal-engine4

So how do i make it work? I script in blueprint, i made a function and ran it, still wouldn't work. I'm making a health and armor bar.

Comment: Recommend adding screenshots and otherwise additional details of what you've tried + what hasn't worked